# [VSCode][CMake][clang-tidy] error: PCH file uses an older PCH format that is no longer supported

Tags: cmake, clang-tidy

First of all:

- My project is on CMake tools
- I'm working in VSCode workspace
- I'm trying to using clang-tidy as code static checking

What i entounter:

- Some of CMake targets enable pch `target_precompile_headers`

when that enables, clang-tidy checking work broke down, throw error like:

```
error: PCH file uses an older PCH format that is no longer supported [clang-diagnostic-error]
```

any idea to compat these two? `target_precompile_headers` & clang-tidy works fine.

Comment: Make sure the `clang++` and `clang-tidy` versions are the same.